# Display app setting in a WP7 ListBox control

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, appsettings, listbox-control

I have a ListBox control which is binded to a `ObservableCollection`.

My XAML code:

```
<ListBox Margin="12,148,12,90" ItemsSource="{Binding FuelRecords}" Name="ListBox1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="Fuel quantity: {Binding Quantity}" FontSize="20" />
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I want to display a unit of measure (litre, gallon), after the quantity. The measurement unit is saved using `IsolatedStorageSettings` in the `AppSettings` class (`VolumeSetting`property).

End result:
Fuel quantity: 23.45 gallon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public class Fuel
{
    public double QuantityGallons { get; set; }

    public double Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return QuantityGallons * (AppSettings["VolumeSetting"] == Units.Pounds) ? 1.5 : 1.0;
        }
    }

    public string Units
    {
        get
        {
            return (AppSettings["VolumeSetting"] == Units.Pounds) ? "pound" : "gallon";
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Fuel quantity: " FontSize="20" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="20" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Units}" FontSize="20" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The _VolumeSetting_ is a constant. I read it from the 'AppSettings' class.